# drawInRect:boxRect vs CGContextDrawImage

Tags: iphone, ios, image-resizing

I have tried to make a draw resizable image but couldn't able to figure this out.
When I use

> ```
> UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout-bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
> [bgImage drawInRect:boxRect];
> ```

it gives the following output
 [image]

instead of resizing it breaks the image.

but if I use

> ```
> UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout-bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
> CGContextDrawImage(context, boxRect, bgImage.CGImage);
> ```

it gives the following output 
[image]

now instead of resizing its stretching the image.

I have searched over internet but not able to solve my problem. can anyone help me. Please note I dont want to addthis in any subview.

my original image is(it has transparency that why its looking grayish from middle)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is at the insets. Your original image is **100x100px** and you set your insets to be **50px** for any of the four edges (top,left,bottom,right). That means that your image now is sliced like this:

[image]

Do you notice what's wrong? There is nothing to repeat!

So if we render the image we get this:

[image]

Now what we really want is to make the insets so that we keep the rounded corners and repeat everything else. Something like this (this is with **20px** insets):

[image]

Which of course give us the desired results when rendered :)

[image]

So the only thing that needs to be changed is:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout-bg"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
```